# Prevent last action repetition on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I am using **asp.net web forms update panel**. Last request is repeated when I refresh a page. So when I delete a record then refresh a page One more record is **deleted**. If I weren't using `UpdatePanel` the solution would be to redirect after deleting but since I am using it (UpdatePanel,Ajax) I don't want the whole page to be reloaded.

How do I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use core ajax or jquery ajax for deletion
this wont repeated on browser refresh